# Listing distributions in Python

Tags: python

I have a sheet of numbers, separated by spaces into columns. Each column represents a different category, and within each column, each number represents a different value. For example, column number four represents age, and within the column, the number 5 represents an age of 44-55. Obviously, each row is a different person's record. I'd like to use a Python script to search through the the sheet, and find all columns where the sixth column is number "1." After that, I want to know how many times each number in column one appears where the number in column six is equal to "1." The script should output to the user that "While column six equals '1', the value '1' appears 12 times in column one. The value '2' appears 18 times..." etc. I hope I'm being clear here. I just want it to list the numbers, basically. Anyway, I'm new to Python. I've attached my code below. I think I should be using dictionaries, but I'm just not totally sure how. So far, I haven't really come close to figuring this out. I would really appreciate if someone could walk me through the logic that would be behind such code. Thank you so much!

```
ldata = open("list.data", "r")
income_dist = {} 

for line in ldata:
    linelist = line.strip().split(" ")
key_income_dist = linelist[6] 
if key_income_dist in income_dist: 
    income_dist[key_income_dist] = 1 + income_dist[key_income_dist] 
else:
        income_dist[key_income_dist] = 1 

ldata.close()

print value_no_occupations
```

Comment: can you put up your list.data?

Comment: Sure, here it is: http://ul.to/wt13co03

Comment: What is the problem with your current code? Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and actual and expected outputs)?

Comment: It just doesn't provide the output I'm looking for. Basically I want the total instances of each number in column one where column six equals "1." I want results like 1: 23, 2: 49, 3: 84... etc. (Although the the second numbers in that list are not correct). Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, indentation is majorly important in Python and the above is bad: the 5 lines following `linelist = line.strip().split(" ")` need to be indented to be in the loop like they should be.

Next they should be indented further and this line added before them:

```
    if len(linelist)>6 and linelist[6]=="1":
```

This line skips over short lines (there are some), and tests for what you said you wanted: "*where column six equals "1."*"  This is column [6] where the first number on the line is referenced as [0] (these are "offsets", not "cardinal", or counting, numbers).

You'll probably want to change `key_income_dist = linelist[6]` to `key_income_dist = linelist[0]` or `[1]` to get what you want.  Play around if necessary.

Finally, you should say `print income_dist` at the end to get a look at your results.  If you want fancier output, study up on [formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

Answer (score 2):

This is actually easier than it seems! The key is `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

ldata = open("list.data")

rows = [tuple(row.split()) for row in ldata if row.split()[5]==1]
# warning this will break if some rows are shorter than 6 columns

first_col = Counter(item[0] for item in rows)
```

If you want the distribution of every column (not just the first) do:

```
distribution = {column: Counter(item[column] for item in rows) for column in range(len(rows[0]))}
# warning this will break if all rows are not the same size!
```

Comment: The code is just beautiful.  When I try to run it and place a `print first_col` at the end, I got just an output "Counter()".  What did I miss?  For your convenience I included some test data in my answer to this problem.

Comment: @lessthanl0l I don't know, but here's my GUESS: `rows = [tuple(row.split()) for row in ldata if row.split()[5]==1]` will only work if `row.split()` returns `int`s, which is (in fact), never. I wrote it that way only because that was how the original question was phrased, and I never thought twice about it. Try instead `if row.split()[5]=="1"]` and see if that doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Following your original program logic, I come up with this version:

```
ldata = open("list.data", "r")

# read in all the rows, note that the list values are strings instead of integers
linelist = []
for line in ldata:
    linelist.append(tuple(line.strip().split(" ")))
ldata.close()

# keep only the rows with 6th column = '1'
only1 = []
for row in linelist:
    if row[5] == '1':
        only1.append(row)

# tally the statistics
income_dist = {}
for row in only1:
    if row[0] in income_dist:
        income_dist[row[0]] += 1
    else:
        income_dist[row[0]] = 1

# print result
print "While column six equals '1',"
for num in sorted(income_dist):
    print "the value %s appears %d times in column one." % (num, income_dist[num])
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the data file has ~9000 rows of data, if you don't want to keep the original data, you can combine step 1 & 2 to make the program use less memory and a little faster.

```
ldata = open("list.data", "r")

# read in all the rows, note that the list values are strings instead of integers
# keep only the rows with 6th column = '1'
only1 = []
for line in ldata:
    if line.strip() == '':      # ignor blank lines
        continue
    row = tuple(line.strip().split(" "))
    if row[5] == '1':
        only1.append(row)
ldata.close()

# tally the statistics
income_dist = {}
for row in only1:
    if row[0] in income_dist:
        income_dist[row[0]] += 1
    else:
        income_dist[row[0]] = 1

# print result
print "While column six equals '1',"
for num in sorted(income_dist):
    print "the value %s appears %d times in column one." % (num, income_dist[num])
```

Sample Test Data in `list.data`:

```
9 2 1 5 4 5 5 3 3 0 1 1 7 NA
9 1 1 5 5 5 5 3 5 2 1 1 7 1
9 2 1 3 5 1 5 2 3 1 2 3 7 1
1 2 5 1 2 6 5 1 4 2 3 1 7 1
1 2 5 1 2 6 3 1 4 2 3 1 7 1
8 1 1 6 4 8 5 3 2 0 1 1 7 1
1 1 5 2 3 9 4 1 3 1 2 3 7 1
6 1 3 3 4 1 5 1 1 0 2 3 7 1
2 1 1 6 3 8 5 3 3 0 2 3 7 1
4 1 1 7 4 8 4 3 2 0 2 3 7 1
1 1 5 2 4 1 5 1 1 0 2 3 7 1
4 2 2 2 3 2 5 1 2 0 1 1 5 1
8 2 1 3 6 6 2 2 4 2 1 1 7 1
7 2 1 5 3 5 5 3 4 0 2 1 7 1
1 1 5 2 3 9 4 1 3 1 2 3 7 1
6 1 3 3 4 1 5 1 1 0 2 3 7 1
2 1 1 6 3 8 5 3 3 0 2 3 7 1
4 1 1 7 4 8 4 3 2 0 2 3 7 1
1 1 5 2 4 9 5 1 1 0 2 3 7 1
4 2 2 2 3 2 5 1 2 0 1 1 5 1
```